# Random wave files using an array as the list of files

Tags: android, media-player

Tyring to code a random .wav file to play using an array for the list. There will be several buttons and each will play a different set of random files from seperate arrays. Can't seem to get the MediaPlayer.create to accept the file name, even though the Toast shows the name.

```
package com.golf.testwaves;


import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    static final String [] badshot =   { "allthat", "happy10", "happy27", "happy4", "inhole1"
            };

    MediaPlayer sayIt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button a = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    a.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Random r = new Random();
    String random1 = badshot [r.nextInt(4)];
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,random1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Verify what .raw file was picked.
    sayIt = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.happy4); // This needs to be where it picks the random .wav file.
    sayIt.start();



}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

I used the "happy4" to ensure that the code works for one .wav file. But still can't seem to figure out the syntax for using the random1 for the file name.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.-

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(random1, "raw", getPackageName());
sayIt = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, resId);
```

Comment: Glad it helped :) By the way, if the answer was useful, please, consider upvoting/accepting it, so it'll help other user too.